# RxJS takeUntil - catchError order

Tags: rxjs

I'm wondering about the best approach when using both takeUntil and catchError operators.

1. If we approach an error the stream should be completed so takeUntil is omitted no matter where it is placed, right?
2. If there's no error and we want to trigger takeUntil it should be placed after catchError due to inner observable possibility between takeUntil and catchError.

I've two thoughts which lead me to a conclusion that takeUntil should be placed after catchError. I'm kindly asking for your point of view, thanks :)

Comment: Where I don't follow you is that with `catchError` the stream won't get completed. Do you have a code sample to share ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer.

Ah, true. I thought about something like:
apiCall().pipe(catchError( () =>{*return error handler*}, takeUntil(condition$)  ).subscribe()

Without catchError the stream would be completed but due to this operator the flow can continue because it returns an observable so takeUntil is needed, is it right?